# How to save input taken through text field using a save button using net beans?

Tags: java, swing, button, netbeans, textfield

I am a beginner in programming and using net beans java for my work. can someone please tell how can I save input data that I have taken from user using text field in the gui? Here is the code for input:

```
private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                                     
// TODO add your handling code here:     
}     

private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
{                                            
    char b_no = evt.getKeyChar();
    if (!(Character.isDigit(b_no)) || (b_no==KeyEvent.VK_BACKSPACE) ||b_no==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))
    {       
    getToolkit().beep(); 
    evt.consume(); 
    }// TODO add your handling code here: 
}
```

I need help on how I should save this input

Comment: Please try to post formatted code only. Please put a little more effort into your question, telling us more about where you're stuck, what your code does or does not do. A little effort will go a long way towards helping us help you.

Comment: My code basically inputs two values from the user, values should be integer only, I am new to java I am not sure if I am taking the input in the right syntax or not

Comment: "_Save input data_" is a bit vague. Do you just want to put it into a variable? Maybe save it in a file? What do you mean by "save" it?

Comment: I want to save the input into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to add a KeyListener to a JTextField, then don't. This should **never** be done as it will mess up the functionality of the JTextField. Instead if you're trying to limit input to text, then consider using :

- a JFormattedTextField with a decent MaskFormatter. For example, [formatted text field tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), or
- add a DocumentFilter to your JTextField's Document to limit the input to numeric or
- Use an InputVerfier to verify that the input is OK
- Or allow any input and verify it simply on JButton press or enter press using an ActionListener. This is the route I'd go as it's the most definitely the easiest to implement. Here in the ActionListener's actionPerformed you'd get the text from the field via `myField.getText()`, check if it is valid by whatever test you wish, and if not valid, clear the text via `myField.setText("")` and send an error message to the user via `JOptionPane.sendMessage(...)` dialog.

Comment: Yup, this seems to pretty much say what I said, but more and better. I'll delete mine and +1

Comment: thank you everyone! please suggest some tutorials for java,since I have no clue how things work

Comment: @irumraza: hover your mouse over the [tag:swing] tag and then click on the info link. There you'll find links to the Swing tutorials. Much luck! Edit: or click [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).